# DATETIME2 IN SSAS TABULAR MODEL

Tags: ssas

I try to import given table and it gives error below:
Data overflow converting to the data type for table 'DWH_FT_07_01_PHYSICAL_PERSON_REGISTRY' column 'C7_BIRTH_DATE'

Data type for this column is datetime2(7)

[ERROR GIVEN BY SSAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q8lN.png)

[TABLE IN DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPNZz.png)

Can I import datetime2 data type in ssas tabular model?